# disable checkbox after checked, android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I want to achieve this : user check on a unchecked checkbox, a toast displayed, the checkbox then become disable..

```
male.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (isChecked){
    Toast.makeText(CheckBoxTuts.this, "male" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    male.setChecked(false);

   }
    }

       });
```

the output failed, because they execute on the same time, even I put the male.setChecked(false) outside.. I can't recall there's something to run something 1st, then other thing.. is it thread? really cant remember

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to achieve: "user check on a unchecked checkbox, a toast displayed, the checkbox then become disable..",you should try this code:

```
male.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {                   
      if (isChecked){
          Toast.makeText(CheckBoxTuts.this, "male" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          male.setEnabled(false); // disable checkbox 
      }
    }    
});
```

Comment: i used ur code to check whether its working but setEnabled(false) doesn't work.

Comment: @ErrorHandler: its not an invalid method,so how it can't work? what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: It stays Checked even though setenabled is false

Comment: @ErrorHandler: it disables checkbox,that doesn't mean changing status of checkbox.it would remain checked only.it would just don't let you change its state once it gets into "checked" state.

Comment: so even the SetChecked(false) works since its gives false while u debug

Comment: @ErrorHandler: he wanted to disable checkbox,not to get it "unchecked"..and you can't disable checkbox using setChecked(false).it changes status of checkbox to false. please read doc and question for more info.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17480/discussion-between-hiral-and-error-handler)

Answer (score 8):

Try this....

**-** Use the `setEnabled(false)` on the `CheckBox`

```
male.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {                   
      if (isChecked){

          Toast.makeText(CheckBoxTuts.this, "male" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          male.setEnabled(false);   // Will Disable checkbox 
      }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `.onClickListener(View.OnClickListener)` with implemented `View.OnClickListener`. In body of implemented method you will check if the CheckBox is checked or not and set them.

Comment: Ohh in fact. To set enabled/disabled state you need to used View.setEnabled(boolean).

Comment: Using View.setVisibilty(int) will set if the component is showing or not.

Comment: You need to check if the checkBox is checked with method `CheckBox.isChecked()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
male.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (isChecked){
   Toast.makeText(CheckBoxTuts.this, "male" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //male.setVisibility(View.GONE);//disappear your check box
    male.setEnabled(false);//disable your check box
}
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

First , Register Your CheckBox to OnCheckedChangeListener.

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

then, Overrides it's Method

```
 @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)
    {
        if (chk.isChecked())
        {
           chk.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```